# djextListTextBox Client Side Validation on XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages

I used dojo ListTextBox 
 with value picker. I need to validate djextListTextBox1 with ClientSide Javascript.

It shouldn't be empty before document is saved.

```
var fldVal = document.getElementByID("#{id:djextListTextBox1}").value;

XSP.getElementById("#{id:djextListTextBox1}").value ;   
XSP.getElementById("#{id:djextListTextBox1}").innerHTML;
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to add any code you have attempted to implement to help people to understand the problem and answer your question. The question is too short and vague.

Comment: var fldVal = document.getElementByID("#{id:djextListTextBox1}").value;

Comment: XSP.getElementById("#{id:djextListTextBox1}").value ;
 XSP.getElementById("#{id:djextListTextBox1}").innerHTML;

Comment: i couldn't get the value of djListTextBox :

Comment: but with displayErrorMessaging design element I did it. but i need to make this validation with CSJS not SSJS :(

Comment: Moved code samples from comments to main question to enhance readability.  Deleted 'thanks' comment.

Comment: Formatted code, added javascript tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dojo list text box is a dojo-based control, so you can use some dojo CSJS to pull out the value. Here's a simple example XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:djextListTextBox id="djextListTextBox1" value="one,two,three,four"></xe:djextListTextBox>
    <xp:button value="Click me" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                var val = dijit.byId("#{id:djextListTextBox1}").getValue();
                console.log(val);]]>
            </xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

When you click the button, it uses dojo to retrieve the values from the dijit-based control, and prints them to the browser console.

[image: Console output for dijit values]

Comment: Great. Perhaps time to learn a bit more about StackOverflow and how to best make use of this great site/tool. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer